# How to get the relevant day of week from Calendar dialog instead of previously selected day

Tags: java, arraylist, calendar

**What I'm looking for :** 
When any date is selected, output the relevant string of day which is "Mon, Tue,...,Sun"

**What I have done :** 
I have an edit text view which is to select a date and the format of date is MM/dd/YY. 
This works well.

**What is going wrong:**
Initially, when I select a date(not current date) string output the "current day" Not the one I selected now. When I select another date, string shows the previously(in this case the one selected initially) selected day. Simply it is like storing the previous day string.

**My code :**

```
Datelistner = CustomDateTimePicker.getCustomDatePicker(DateEditText,null,myCalander);
            DateEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),Datelistner,
                            myCalander.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                            myCalander.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                            myCalander.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                            selectedDateIndex = myCalander.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

                        ArrayList<String> dateString = new ArrayList<String>();
                        dateString.add("Sun");
                        dateString.add("Mon");
                        dateString.add("Tue");
                        dateString.add("Wed");
                        dateString.add("Thu");
                        dateString.add("Fri");
                        dateString.add("Sat");

                        selectedDate = dateString.get(selectedDateIndex - 1);

                        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date().getTime());
                        datePickerDialog.setCancelable(false);
                        datePickerDialog.show();

                    }
            });
            updateLabelAddEvent();

private void updateLabelAddEvent() {
    String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.getDefault());
    DateEditText.setText(sdf.format(myCalander.getTime()));

}
```

I have already defined the string variable(selectedDate) and int variable (selectedDateIndex) as global (during oncreate).

I'm just wondering whether how to fix this.

Comment: I believe you need to override the `onDateSet` method of your date picker. It’s not my home field, so said with some reservation.

Comment: override with what? I mean what is meant by reservation

Answer (score 1):

## Zero-based counting

The terrible `Calendar` class has many poor design decisions. One of those is counting day-of-week as zero-based. So first day is 0, last is 7. Looks like you are subtracting one to get a zero-based index into your array, not realizing you already have a zero-based number. So stop subtracting.

## Week definition varies

Another problem is that the definition of a week in `Calendar` varies by locale.

## *java.time*

More important, you should be using the modern *java.time* classes rather than the bloody awful legacy date-time classes.

### Current moment by zone

Get current date-time as seen in a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

### Generate text

Get the day of week using the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum built into Java.

```
DayOfWeek dow = zdt.getDayOfWeek() ;
```

Automatically localize. No need for that array of yours listing day names.

Specify a `Locale` to determine the human language and cultural norms for localization.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;  // Or Locale.US or such. 
String output = dow.getDisplayName( TextStyle.SHORT , locale ) ;
```

### Converting

To interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert. Call new to/from methods added to the old classes.

`ZonedDateTime` class replaces `GregorianCalendar`, the usual concrete class behind `Calendar`. So cast.

```
Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;
```

And:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ( ( GregorianCalendar ) c ).toZonedDateTime() ;
```

I see you also use `java.util.Date`. Replaced by `Instant` to represent a moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

And:

```
java.util.Date myJavaUtilDate = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;
```

You can get an `Instant` from your `ZonedDateTime`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. When I started on editing as per the description, in my android studio (3.5) it says that  API 26 is required in the step of "  ZoneId.of"

Comment: @SachzEMSPE You should have tagged with “Android”. I’ll add a section about ThreeTen-Backport and ThreeTenABP.